# Автозаполнение поля select по названии страницы

Tags: javascript

Суть такая, есть название страницы и нужно чтобы с выпадающего списка `option` совпадал с названием страницы. Может кто то делал такое на `javascript`?

Как делал я:

```
pgtitle = $("title").text();
if (pgtitle=='название')
{
    $('#regger select#course option').hide();
    $('#regger select option:contains("название")').show();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Нет, никто не делал. Но нас это не остановит.

```
$('#course option').each(function(){
  if ($(this).text() == pgtitle)
    $('#course').val(this.value);
});
```

---

```
$('#course').val( $('#course option').filter((i, el) => $(el).text() == pgtitle).val() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Всем привет. Спасибо кто подсказал мне. 
Скрипт работает, может кому то будет нужен. Дело в том, что прописывать тайтл нужно для каждой страницы (название должно быть полным). Мы скрываем ненужные селекты и сотавляем только те которые нужно.

```
pgtitle = $("title").text();
if (pgtitle=='название')
{
    $('#regger select#course option').hide();
    $('#regger select option:contains("название")').show();
}
if (pgtitle=='название1')
{
    $('#regger select#course option').hide();
    $('#regger select option:contains("название1")').show();
}
```